# Appending two strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to write code to append two strings without the function strcat, but it doesn't work. It only works when the inputs are a single char.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
    Return the result of appending the characters in s2 to s1.
    Assumption: enough space has been allocated for s1 to store the extra
    characters.
*/
char* append (char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int s1len = strlen (s1);
    int s2len = strlen (s2);
    int k;
    for (k=0; k<s2len; k++) {
        s1[k+s1len] = s2[k];
    }
    return s1;
}

int main ( ) {
    char str1[10];
    char str2[10];
    while (1) {
        printf ("str1 = ");
        if (!gets(str1)) {
            return 0;
        };
        printf ("str2 = ");
        if (!gets(str2)) {
            return 0;
        };
        printf ("The result of appending str2 to str1 is %s.\n",
            append (str1, str2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check that https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `s1` must be terminated; `k <= s2len` should do this.   Programs seems to be prone to overflows (`str1[10]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

1. **Do not use `gets`**. This function is dangerous because it doesn't take the
   size of the buffer into account. Use `fgets` instead.
2. Your `append` function does not write the `'\0'`-terminating byte. It should
   be

   ```
   char* append (char s1[], char s2[]) {
       int s1len = strlen (s1);
       int s2len = strlen (s2);
       int k;
       for (k=0; k<s2len; k++) {
           s1[k+s1len] = s2[k];
       }
       s1[k+s1len] = 0; // writing the 0-terminating byte
       return s1;
   }
   ```
3. `str1` may be to short for holding both strings. If `str2` contains `"Hello"`
   and `str2` contains `"World!"`, you are going to overflow the buffer. Make the
   buffer larger.

If you writing your own `strcat`, I would pass the size of the destination
buffer as well, so that you don't overflow the buffers:

```
char *mystrcat(char *t1, const char *t2, size_t maxsize)
{
    if(t1 == NULL || t2 == NULL)
        return NULL;

    size_t s1 = strlen(t1);
    size_t s2 = strlen(t2);

    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < s2 && (s1 + i) < maxsize - 1 ; ++i)
        t1[i + s1] = t2[i];

    t1[i + s1] = 0; // terminating the

    return t1;
}


int main(void)
{
    char str1[30] = "Hello ";
    char str2[30] = "World!";

    printf("mystrcat(\"%s\", \"%s\") = %s\n", str1, str2,
            mystrcat(str1, str2, sizeof str1));

    char str3[100] = "This is a long sentence";

    printf("mystrcat(\"%s\", \"%s\") = %s\n", str1, str3,
            mystrcat(str1, str3, sizeof str1));

    char line[100];
    printf("Enter some text: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // removing possible newline

    strcpy(str3, "User input was: ");

    printf("mystrcat: %s\n", mystrcat(str3, line, sizeof str3));

    return 0;
}
```

That would return

```
mystrcat("Hello World!", "World!") = Hello World!
mystrcat("Hello World!This is a long se", "This is a long sentence") = Hello World!This is a long se
Enter some text: ABC DEF user input is great
mystrcat: User input was: ABC DEF user input is great
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your resulting string is not properly terminated.

  Strings in C are **always** terminated with a NUL (0) character.
- `gets` is unsafe, use `fgets` instead.
- Get in the habit to check buffer sizes.

To give you an idea, here a minimalistic implementation using fgets + buffer size checks:

```c
#include <stdio.h>  // fprintf, fgets
#include <string.h> // strlen

const char *concatenate(char *dst, size_t sz, const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t l1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t l2 = strlen(s2);

    // Check for overflow
    if ((l1 + l2 + 1) > sz) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Copy first string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l1; ++i) {
        dst[i] = s1[i];
    }

    // Copy second string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l2; ++i) {
        dst[l1 + i] = s2[i];
    }

    // Add NUL terminator
    dst[l1 + l2 + 1] = 0;

    return dst;
}

int main() {
    // Allocate two strings (9 chars max.)
    char first_string[10];
    char second_string[10];
    char concatenated_string[20];

    // Read first string from stdin
    fprintf(stdout, "str1 = ");
    // !!! fgets return value check omitted for simplicity.
    fgets(first_string, sizeof(first_string), stdin);

    // Read second string from stdin
    fprintf(stdout, "str2 = ");
    // !!! fgets return value check omitted for simplicity.
    fgets(second_string, sizeof(second_string), stdin);

    const char *tmp = concatenate(concatenated_string, sizeof(concatenated_string), first_string, second_string);

    if (!tmp) {
         fprintf(stderr, "would overflow\n");
    } else {
         fprintf(stdout, "concatenated: %s\n", concatenated_string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `concatenate` returning a `const char*`?

Comment: @Pablo Good question. The answer is that I got into the habit making every pointer `const` (if possible). Of course, logically speaking `char *` would've made more sense.

Comment: Do you mean every pointer everywhere or just pointers in the function arguments? Why do you do that? A function that modifies a string in place and returns a pointer to it, should not be `const`, because the function already modified it.